# Convert an .sql file from a SQLBase server in to SSMS

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sqlbase

I am attempting to convert a .sql file from a SQLBase server in to SSMS but am having trouble doing so.  The file contains queries that will create a database with 600+ tables and their data.  The file has over 33 million lines.  How can I convert this to a format that will work in SSMS? Ex. of differences is double quotes in the insert statements. Any help is appreciated.

I have attempted a find and replace on double quotes to single quotes but this doesnt work due to double quotes being contained inside the strings being inserted.  I have attempted to Google search ways to convert this but everything for SQLBase that I am finding is from 15+ years ago.

Comment: You obviously haven't looked very hard to find ( recent ) SQLBase manuals. Go here: https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/    to get recent manuals, and see my answer below on how to LOAD your .sql file back into SQLBase, then use the SQLServer Import/Export wizard to  extract in a SQLServer friendly syntax .

Answer (score 0):

You will go mad before you get a SQLBase unload file to build a SQLServer schema and load the data  into it.

There is a better way - but you need SQLBase to be up and running.

You obviously haven't looked very hard to find ( recent ) SQLBase manuals. Go here: [SQLBase Manuals / Release Notes etc](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/)

SQLBase is now up to v12.3 and 64bit - current and popular,  so it depends on the version of the unload file you have.

If you **don't** have SQLBase running, you can go to the OpenText mother site, download a trial version of SQLBase  [Download SQLBase here](https://www.opentext.com/products/gupta-sqlbase), ( or shock horror - actually buy  a copy ), load your .sql file into it using the SQLTalk LOAD command ( See the manuals mentioned earlier for the syntax  ), then when you have a coherent SQLBase dB running, use the SQLServer Import/ Export wizard to connect to SQLBase via its native OLEdB driver and to SQLServer via its OLEdB driver, and then create a whole load of .dtsx packages which you can then run to load into a SQLServer instance. I've just done it - and its quite straight forward apart from a few data type mismatches..

p.s. If you need proper help with this option - there is heaps of SQLBase expertise on the 'Team Developer SQLWindows Community Forum' here:   [SQLBase Expertise](https://forum.tdcommunity.net/index.php)